# How to make an outgtoing TCP connection through specified netwrok interface?

Tags: networking, sockets, tcp-ip

Is there a way to implement in C program a next feature: it's need to making outgoing TCP connections through specified network interface? as example:

eth0 - 172.16.0.1
eth1 - 192.168.1.1

In some case I'm need to make outgoing connections from source address 172.16.0.1, and under some other circumstances from 192.168.1.1.

Is this possible ? 
Is this can be achieved with bind() routine?

TIA.

Comment: Maybe https://stackoverflow.com/q/14478167/5830574

Comment: Thanks, useful topic. But I'm don't need to bind a listening socket but socket for outgoing connection.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/335607/5830574 They also suggest `setsockopt()`.

Comment: Ok. Thanks again. I just will check it with test code ...

Comment: setsockopt(#3, SO_BINDTODEVICE, enp0s3:1)->19 - it;s looks like that BINDTODEV is no works for the pseudo-interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Use command line parameter to assign the local address in following way

struct sockaddr_in localaddr;

localaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;

localaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("172.16.0.1");

localaddr.sin_port = 0;  // Any local port will do

bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&localaddr, sizeof(localaddr));

And when you want to use other IP then use it instead of 172.16.0.1